# Flutter notification: A background message could not be handled in Dart as no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Whenever my app receives a notification from Firebase I get the following message in the console:

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 5688): broadcast received for message
W/FLTFireMsgService( 5688): A background message could not be handled in Dart as no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered.
```

The data received by the notification are also showing null. How can I solve this problem?

**Here's the code that handles notifications:**

```
AppStateProvider() {
//    _subscribeUser();
    _saveDeviceToken();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage
        .listen((RemoteMessage message) => handleOnMessage(message.data));

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
        .listen((RemoteMessage message) => handleOnResume(message.data));

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (message != null) {
        return handleOnLaunch(message.data);
      }
    });

    //FirebaseMessaging.onMessage;
    //FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp;

    _getUserLocation();
    Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen(_userCurrentLocationUpdate);
  }

Future handleOnMessage(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    _handleNotificationData(data);
    print('Message data: $data');
  }

  Future handleOnLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    _handleNotificationData(data);
    print('Message data: $data');
  }

  Future handleOnResume(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    _handleNotificationData(data);
    print('Message data: $data');
  }

  _handleNotificationData(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    hasNewRideRequest = true;
    rideRequestModel = RideRequestModel.fromMap(data['data']);
    riderModel = await _riderServices.getRiderById(rideRequestModel.userId);
    //print(riderModel?.name);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: You have to set up a background notification handler, [see here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#background_messages).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an `onBackgroundMessage` handler by following these steps:

1. Declare `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` as a top level
   function in `main.dart`
2. Initialize background message handler `onBackgroundMessage` in `main()` method

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  printLog("Handling a background message: $message");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```